# Jetpack Compose: remember is returning the "wrong" value

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm stuck on a Compose issue.

I can't figure out why the `remember { mutableStateOf() }` is returning the wrong value.

For example:

```
val subscribedState: State<Boolean> = remember { mutableStateOf(data.isSubscribed) }
```

When I debug this, the `data.isSubscribed` evaluates to `true`, but `subscribedState` evaluates to `false`.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: They don't have to match. `data.isSubscribed` is the initial value of `subscribedState`, when it is changed, the state will not change, since it is remembered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A value computed by [remember](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-in-composables) is stored in the Composition during initial composition, and the stored value is returned during recomposition.

This means when your function makes initial composition, `subscribedState` will keep first value of `data.isSubscribed` even if `data.isSubscribed` was changed

I think `data.isSubscribed` is already your state.

Besides you can update state inside `remember` by passing any argument.

Example:

```
val subscribedState: State<Boolean> = remember(data.isSubscribed) { mutableStateOf(data.isSubscribed) }
```

but more elegant(I guess `data.isSubscribed` is already your state):

```
val subscribedState = data.isSubscribed
```